# angular-translate is not translating with loaded static file

Tags: angular-translate

I'm using the following angular files for translations:

- angular-translate.min.js (v2.2.0)
- angular-translate-loader-static-files.min.js (v2.2.0)
- angular-translate-storage-cookie.min.js (v2.2.0 )
- angular-translate-storage-local.min.js (v2.2.0)
- angular-cookies.min.js (v1.2.22)

**angular-translate** works when I do the following:

```
$translateProvider.translations('en_us', {
    "label.test": "It works."
});
```

But not when I attempt to use a static file...

My HTML:

```
<html data-ng-app="myApp">
...
{{"label.test" | translate}}
```

My app.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies', 'pascalprecht.translate']).config(['$translateProvider', function($translateProvider) {
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en_us');
    $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
        prefix: '/app/resources/messages/i18n_',
        suffix: '.json'
    });
    $translateProvider.useLocalStorage();
    $translateProvider.storageKey('lang');
}]);
```

My Get Response (with Content-Type set to: application/json):

```
{
    "label.test":"It works from JSON."
};
```

**The rendered HTML page shows**: label.test

Additionally, there are no errors in my console. I also tried renaming the key to TEST, but that didn't work, either.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you use the translate directive instead of the filter. `<p translate="label.test"></p>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the path to your .json is correct. If it is not found, in your template, it will just print out `label.test` instead of the actual translation `It works from JSON.` just like it is doing.

Your app root is most likely app, so if your translation file is located in `/app/resources/messages/i18n_en_us.json` then try:

```
$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
    prefix: '/resources/messages/i18n_',
    suffix: '.json'
});
```

Also make sure your JSON is valid JSON.  Remove the semi-colon at the end.

```
{
    "label.test":"It works from JSON."
}
```

Comment: Hi BigHeadCreations - it was the semi-colon. I removed it and both of the following now work: `{{"label.test" | translate}}` and `<p translate="label.test"></p>` Thanks so much!

Comment: i know it is an older post, but just to add it once more.. it is really important that the path is correct.. if you are not sure.. you can try to put that in your browser and try to find out the correct path until something shows up.. or see in your browser debuging if your json file under network-> XHR shows the correct content, then you are sure that this path which you setup is correct.